# Entity SQL Anonymous type?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-sql

I have a database with 2 tables :

1. Personal : ID (PK), Name, Code (FK), Birthdate
2. Social : Code (PK), Address

When I add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model name Model to my project. The Model.Context.tt has only Personals and Socials Dbset<>, so i can only choose 2 tables by using query :

```
string sql = "SELECT VALUE p FROM SqlEntities.Personals AS p"
```

SqlEntities is my entity name, so the thing i want is how to make a column in table become the Dbset<>, maybe I don't understand much but how i can use the anonymous type like :

```
stringsql = "SELECT p.ID, p.Name FROM SqlEntities.Personals AS p"
```

[image: Model.Context.tt]

Comment: why the entity framework tag

Comment: Because in Enitty Framework has LINQ and Entity SQL. So I tagged it, if you know solution for my post, you can answer. Thank you !

Comment: Do you know what a `Dbset` is for? Why don't you use LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

With projection, it is possible to make the query return only some columns from one table, or to return selected columns from multiple tables joined together. Projection is done with the `Select()` method and supports anonymous types:

```
db.Personals.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name });
```

Comment: It's work, thank a lot. But the code you post is belong to LINQ or Entity SQL ? Sorry, I have a bad knowledge about this.

Comment: You are welcome. The Select method belongs to LINQ, and is in all LINQ-to-something technologies (including LINQ-to-SQL).

Comment: Thanks for your explaning, but I wonder if there is any way to select a column like that but use the query string in ESQL ?